# How to use application lock in SQL server from two databases

Tags: sql-server, locking

How to use a lock from two different databases. When a session acquires the lock, there is nothing preventing different session to acquire the same lock from different database.

First session:

```
USE db_one;
EXEC @lock_result = sp_getapplock @Resource = 'my_resource',
                                  @LockMode = 'Exclusive',
                                  @LockTimeout = 30000;
```

Second session:

```
USE db_two;
EXEC @lock_result = sp_getapplock @Resource = 'my_resource',
                                  @LockMode = 'Exclusive',
                                  @LockTimeout = 30000;
```

Second session acquires lock with no delay, instead of waiting for the lock. Now two sessions appear to have the same lock at the same time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider database-qualifying the `sp_getapplock` proc name. This way, the lock will be acquired in the specified database instead of the current session database context.

```
EXEC @lock_result = tempdb..sp_getapplock @Resource = 'my_resource',
    LockMode = 'Exclusive',
    @LockTimeout = 30000;
```

Answer (score 6):

**You can place it in a stored procedure in one of the databases, then execute it with a cross-database call.**

```sql
USE db_one;
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.LockMy_resource
AS

DECLARE @lock_result int;
EXEC @lock_result = sp_getapplock @Resource = 'my_resource',
                                  @LockMode = 'Exclusive',
                                  @LockTimeout = 30000;
RETURN @lock_result;

GO
```

```
USE db_two;
GO

DECLARE @lock_result int;

EXEC @lock_result = db_one.dbo.LockMy_resource;
```